# QThread and Phonon

Tags: qt4, qthread, phonon

I am writing a C++ GUI application using Qt Creator (based on 32-bit QT 4.8.0).  My goal is to create an application which plays nature sounds at random, with various attributes for each sound.  I am trying to use the Phonon library to play these sounds.

I have a class called ZooKeeper which inherits from the public QThread.  This class has a main running function that loops:

```
while(true)
{
   ManageCritters();
   QThread::msleep(10);
}
```

Inside the `ManageCritters();` function, I play sound files based on a file name specific to a particular animal at a given time.  Here is how I execute it:

```
// create our media objects and an audio-output
Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
Phonon::AudioOutput *autioOut = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);

// link the two together
Phonon::createPath(mediaObject, audioOut);

// set our audio source to the filename we want to play
mediaObject->setCurrentSource(filename);

// play the audio file
mediaObject->play();
```

This all compiles just fine - however I get a runtime error:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QThread(0x82c7e48), parent's thread is QThread(0x8166ee8), current thread is QThread(0x82c7e48)
WARNING: Phonon needs QCoreApplication::applicationName to be set to export audio output names through the DBUS interface 
KGlobal::locale() must be called from the main thread before using i18n() in threads. KApplication takes care of this. If not using KApplication, call KGlobal::locale() during initialization.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

It appears as though I am failing to understand how to setup audio plays within QThreads, but I don't see where the error is occurring, nor how to fix it.

Should I have a different setup for handling audio plays?  This is all OOP.  I do have another class called `Critter()` which represents an individual creature (bug, bird, etc.).  Ideally, I would like to have each "critter" handle its own audio playing (make the audio play a function of the `Critter()` class).  But I am not sure how to get this `Critter()` class to link to the Phonon library and play audio files.

Are there any suggestions or example code?

Comment: You might want to steer clear of phonon if this is a new build, as Qt5 doesn't have phonon.

Comment: Good to know - is there another audio library that supports balance adjustment and pitch adjustment?

Comment: I don't know, I only play basic sound files. I am planning on switching to QtMultiMedia QAudioOutput https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaudiooutput.html

Answer (score 1):

put this

```
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName( "phonon" );
```

on the above of the code before u create media object